# break statement not working in function in clips

Tags: rules, rule-engine, clips

the break statement is not working in my code.

error : The break function not valid in this context.

```
(deffunction slabFunction (?q0 ?q1 ?q2)
(if(and(>= ?q0 36)(>= ?q1 36)(>= ?q2 36)) then
(printout t "slab 3" crlf)
(break))
(if(and(>= ?q0 24)(>= ?q1 24)(>= ?q2 24))
then 
(printout t "slab 2" crlf))
(if (and(>= ?q0 12)(>= ?q1 12)(>= ?q2 12))
then 
(printout t "slab 1" crlf)
(break))
)
```

Please help!
If the slab 3 gets applied the other condition shouldnt get applied. If it doesnt, then slab 2 check is done, if statisfied it applies. then no further check is done. so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a break statement to terminate a loop (or in some languages a switch statement). If you want the function to terminate after a condition has been satisfied, use a return statement.

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> 
(deffunction slabFunction (?q0 ?q1 ?q2)
   (if (and (>= ?q0 36) (>= ?q1 36) (>= ?q2 36))
      then
      (printout t "slab 3" crlf)
      (return))
   (if (and (>= ?q0 24) (>= ?q1 24) (>= ?q2 24))
      then 
      (printout t "slab 2" crlf)
      (return))
   (if (and (>= ?q0 12) (>= ?q1 12) (>= ?q2 12))
      then 
      (printout t "slab 1" crlf)
      (return)))
CLIPS> (slabFunction  40 40 40)
slab 3
CLIPS> (slabFunction 26 26 45)
slab 2
CLIPS> (slabFunction 56 13 33)
slab 1
CLIPS> (slabFunction 10 3 2)
FALSE
CLIPS>
```